# How to generate a checkbox from a user-selected value

Tags: php, html, arrays, checkbox

I've an application where at the first page the user is shown four products which he can choose.  After he saves the data, I've to show a list of all four products and put a *"check"* next to the one that the user selected.  I'm having trouble with my logic - can anyone help?

```php
// user can choose from these products
$products = array(
    '1'=>'Product One',
    '2'=>'Product Two',
    '3'=>'Product Three',
    '4'=>'Product Four' );

// user has choosen these products
$selected_products = explode(',', 'Product One,Product Four');
foreach($selected_products as $product)
{
    // Have to print out all products from $products variable, and check 
    // the ones that the user selected from the $selected_products string.
}
```

Comment: Hi @runningmark if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `in_array()` to check whether it is one of the checked choices inside the selected values. Rough example:

```
$products = array('1'=>'Product One','2'=>'Product Two','3'=>'Product Three','4'=>'Product Four');
// user has choosen these products
$selected_products = explode(',', 'Product One,Product Four');
foreach($products as $id => $p) {
    $checked = (in_array($p, $selected_products)) ? 'checked' : '';
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check' value='{$id}' $checked /> {$p}<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the selected products are returned as IDs and not as product names. Then you can use `in_array()` to determine whether a checkbox should be checked.

```
<?php

$products = array(1=>'Product One', 2=>'Product Two', 3=>'Product Three', 4=>'Product Four');
$selectedProducts = array(1,4);

foreach($products as $key => $value) {
    $checked = in_array($key, $selectedProducts) ? ' checked' : '';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" id="product'.$key.'" value="'.$key.'"'.$checked.' /> <label for="product'.$key.'">'.$value.'</label>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
$products = array('1'=>'Product One','2'=>'Product Two','3'=>'Product Three','4'=>'Product Four');
// user has choosen these products
$selected_products = explode(',', 'Product One,Product Four');
foreach($products as $id => $p) {
    $checked = (in_array($p, $selected_products)) ? 'checked' : '';
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check' value='{$id}' $checked /> {$p}<br/>";
}
```